# Screenshot saving error in visual basic.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to save a screenshot with this line:

```
PictureBox1.Image.Save("D:\screenshot" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") & ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

But it says: NullReferenceException was unhandled..

Comment: Sounds like there isn't an image in PictureBox1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
PictureBox1.Image.Save("D:\screenshot\" & DateTime.Now.ToString( _
              "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") & ".jpg", _
              System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

That is, try with a "\" after "screenshot".

Comment: That shouldn't be the source of the exception; an `ExternalException` is thrown when permission is required, and writing to a file with the same name would overwrite that file.

Comment: Without the "\" following "screenshot", the statement is attempting to add a file to the root directory of "D:".  It is possible to permit the adding of folders to a root directory but not, without administrative rights, the adding of files. I do not know how this is achieved but it would explain the exception.

Comment: Well, as mentioned, an `ExternalException` (since this is all done with GDI) is thrown when the application doesn't have access to write to a file or directory. Also, only the root directory of the system drive requires elevation (by default) on Vista and up. `NullReferenceExceptions` are generally thrown when trying to access the member (`Image.Save`) of a reference (`PictureBox1.Image`) that is null.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set an image in the `PictureBox1`? I think you are not setting the picturebox `Image` property to an image but instead you are simply drawing an image on the box, which is not the same thing. If you haven't loaded an Image object into the PictureBox then there's no Image object to call Save on.

Try to look at this example:

```
Private Function DrawText(ByVal Text As String) As Bitmap
    Dim TextBitmap As New Bitmap(100, 100)
    Dim Brush As New SolidBrush(Color.Blue)
    Dim SelectedFont = New Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 40)
    Using Graphic = Graphics.FromImage(TextBitmap)
        Graphic.DrawString(Text, SelectedFont, Brush, 0, 0)
    End Using
    Return TextBitmap
End Function
```

Usage:

```
PictureBox1.Image = DrawText("Hi")    ' Setting an Image to PictureBox1.Image
PictureBox1.Image.Save("D:\HiPic.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

The example above may or may not work since this is `UNTESTED`. But my point is, `SAVE` method will not work unless you set an image to `PictureBox`.`Image` Property.